# Reading rds file into python

Tags: python, load, rds

I am trying to read an rds file in python using the following two sets of code that I found on stackoverflow:

```
import pyreadr
from collections import OrderedDict
result = pyreadr.read_r('Datasets.rds') 
df = result["History"]
```

Which gives me an ordereddict with size 0 and:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import tzlocal
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()
readRDS = robjects.r['readRDS']
df = readRDS('Datasets.rds')
df = pandas2ri.ri2py(df)
```

which does not show anything to me while runs with no error.

Could you please let me know what might be wrong with these codes?